# Can not connect to compute engine VM - No space left on device

Tags: google-compute-engine

I've run into an issue where I can no longer connect to my VM that I could connect to before.

Checking the VMs Observability Tab as well as the servers serial port output shows:

[image: Observability Tab]

```
Aug  2 09:27:14 my-server systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Failed to run 'start' task: No space left on device
Aug  2 09:27:14 my-server systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Failed with result 'resources'.
Aug  2 09:27:14 my-server systemd[1]: Failed to start Login Service.
Aug  2 09:27:14 my-server systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
```

So the likely culprit is simply, that the disk is full.
I've found [this troubleshooting guide](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-disk-full-resize) which I followed,by:

1. Shutting down the VM.
2. Increasing the Boot Disk size from 1000 to 1400 and 1450 in a second attempt.
3. Starting the VM.

Unfortunately that didn't help and I still can't connect. Further steps require me to connect via SSH. It might be worth noting, that I did attempt to increase the size through the web interface first before I found the troubleshooting page. At that point the VM might or might not have been shut down properly. Another change I noticed is, that the VM does no longer report Disk Space Utilization or Memory Utilization in the Observability Tab since it was restarted, however it sill reports other stats.

Under File system issues a it is mentioned that under Debian images `... expand-root.sh[..]: Resizing ext4 filesystem on /dev/sda1.` should appear. While this is an Ubuntu image, I couldn't find anything similar using grep.

So, how could I gain access to the stuff on the VM?

Comment: There are at least two possibilities: 1) The resize did not occur during reboot. 2) The resize failed and the file system is flagged `dirty` which requires a file system check by the `fsck` tool. I recommend that you create a new instance. Create a snapshot of the old instance's disk and restore that snapshot as a second disk. Then copy your data to the new instance. If you know what you are doing with file systems and system repair tools, connect to the system using the VM serial console. Otherwise, just recover your data.

Comment: I recovered my data using this method and transfered it to new VMs. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to:

1. Create a [snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots#create_regional_snapshot) from the affected disk.
2. Create an [additional disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots#creating_a_new_persistent_disk_from_a_snapshot) using the created snapshot
3. After creating the disk from the snapshot, attach it to an another working Linux VM Instance "instance-1" for example, as [additional disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#create_disk), not as the boot disk
4. Then mount the attached disk to a [specific directory](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#mounting).
5. After mounting, You need to free up some space from the mounted disk, to have space for the services needed to recognize the resizing of the disk.
6. After freeing up some space, you need to re-attach the disk as the boot disk to test if you had regain control of the VM Instance.

Comment: Thanks, this is essentially what I did, except rather than modifying the disk, I rescued the data and reestablished it in fresh VMs.